# React change fetch data key from Home page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

Maybe somebody can help me, I need to set a key for my data, how can I do it from Home.jsx page..?
**API:**

```
<?php
$images = [
    "logo" => "http://www.cbp-exercises.test/cowboy_cafe_react/cowboy-coffee-shop/src/api/img/logo.svg", 
    "counter" => "http://www.cbp-exercises.test/cowboy_cafe_react/cowboy-coffee-shop/src/api/img/counter.jpg",
];

echo json_encode($images);
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Counter from '../components/Home/Counter';
import "../style/Home.scss"

function Home() {

    return (
         <section class="main">
        <div class="main_title">
            <h1>Generic Hipster Coffee</h1>
            <h2>Specialty coffee, fresh food & local community.</h2>
        </div>
       <Counter img = 'counter'/>          -----> here I wanna set the key for data
        </section>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**Counter.js**

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { useEffect } from "react"
const Counter = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  const [dataLoaded, setDataLoaded] = useState(false)
  const loadData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "http://www.cbp-exercises.test/cowboy_cafe_react/cowboy-coffee-shop/src/api/images.php"
    )
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)

    setData(data)
    setDataLoaded(true)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    loadData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div class='main_img'>
      {dataLoaded ? (
        <>
          <img src={data.props.img} alt='counter' />  -----> here should be my props
        </>
      ) : (
        <p>We will have data here... later</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Counter
```

If I set `<img src={data.counter}>` all working, but if I use my props.img there will be an error : **Counter.js:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img')**
Where is a problem? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use src={data.props.img} ? Use just src={props.img} instead.

Comment: In this case I just get a 'counter' instead of image from data.counter.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand fully at first. If data is an object with a key "counter", you can do src={data[props.img]}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property is important when you map your array, but in your code, there is no any array which should be mapped.
Secondly, You put in home.jsx props "img", you can use this props in counter components like: `props.img` or destructure in function arguments like ({img}) and use as `img`.